# How to direct another page in JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp, if-statement, web

```
    <jsp:setProperty name="firstBean" property="sifre" /><br/>


    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${firstBean.sifreKntrl()}">
    Hosgeldin!
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;firma.html">

    </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

It works when I use **if else condition** by <% %> syntax but I am unable to redirect to another page with **else** condition. Because of directive problem I used EL but now I couldn't make the code worked. That makes works both of the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the redirect tag to do so. The below code works for me.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="CONDITION">
        <c:redirect url="PAGE1.jsp"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:redirect url="PAGE2.jsp"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```